# Why does Firefox show an extra line here?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Been trying my hardest to remove the extra line space (or padding, margin, whatever it is) from this page in firefox:

http://emctalk.com.au/

See the menu? compare that to chrome, and you'll notice the menu sits too far below the background, making the layout seem broken.

Anyway I tried adding `line-height: 1px` to the UL item and then taking out the `height` on the LI elements, making them as small as they can possibly be.

This actually makes it look normal, but this way, I feel is a hack. I'm interested to know what the actual problem is so that I can solve it in the future.

If anyway has some advice on how to fix it, that would be greatly appreciated. I am using FF5, and the latest Google Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: use CSS reset. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Please validate your HTML (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Femctalk.com.au%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) so that we know that it's not a difference due to rendering invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following in your CSS:

```
/* http://emctalk.com.au/site/assets/template/css/base.css?v2( line: 375 )*/

.home a {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    text-indent: -2000em;
}
```

to

```
/* http://emctalk.com.au/site/assets/template/css/base.css?v2( line: 375 )*/

.home a {
    display: block;
    height: 140px; /*The height 150px causes the problem*/
    text-indent: -2000em;
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the calculation of the height of `#mainmenu li` when set as `display:inline`.  Mozilla must be using the padding-top and padding-bottom 13px to calculate where to place the background tick image.

In firebug, I change padding and height settings below to get the intended result.

```
#mainmenu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
#mainmenu {
float:left;
}
```

include this in the css and adjust the background as per ui.